# Adding a reference + using directive doesn't 'load' the assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I added a reference to a different solution assembly to my project.
I also added a using directive

```
using MyAssembly;
```

MyAssembly only exposes one type `MyClass`.

However when I want to reference it in code I still have to write full name:

```
MyAssembly.MyClass
```

Isn't the using statement suppose to solve that? The reason is, I'm getting expections that the MyClass type cannot be found.

Comment: It could be that there are 2 `MyClass` in 2 different namespace

Comment: It is a _using directive_ not _using statement_ by the way. They are different things.

Comment: **MyAssembly only exposes one type MyClass.** please show us where you define `MyClass`? directly in namespace? in another class in namespace?

Comment: It was throwing exception because It was pointing do a wrong assembly path :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're having same class `myClass` on both solutions. Hence, you will need to explicitly provide the assembly name in order to let the compiler know which class of both you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible when you reference higher .Net framework version build dll to lower .Net framework Projects. This is very common issue. But agreed that you face the same issue when you have same class defined in two dlls.